# memcpy not working as expected

Tags: c

Here is the deal:

```
void* target_adrr = //adress to copy data to
void* source_adrr = //adress to copy data from
unsigned long data_size = //the size in bytes
memcpy(target_adrr, source_adrr, data_size);
```

The code work on the 1st run. On the 2nd run, other data are altered, something not expected. I noticed memcpy returns some address. This address has no connection with my target address.

I am pretty confused, can someone please help me?

Comment: At a guess,you got `data_size` wrong

Comment: No, it's pretty correct. What kind of address memcpy returns?

Comment: Could be anything. You have managed to omit all the crucial details.

Comment: Not sure what to post

Comment: What kind of adress memcpy returns?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms859670.aspx

Comment: memcpy returns the destination address. You coukd have learnt that from the documentation. Why did you ask a question about your code and omit the code? Or did you really use uninitialised variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the return value different between the function calls?

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dswaw1wk.aspx), the chance of an undefined behavior is:

> If the source and destination overlap, the behavior of memcpy is undefined. Use memmove to handle overlapping regions.

Sounds like yours. Is that it?